# Memory leak in stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm implementing a stack by C++ and here I think it has memory leakage problem: in `Stack::peek()` and `Stack::pop()`, where I created heap space and returned pointer to function caller.

Users who call these two functions may perform deletion on returned pointer, which will recycle heap space once done. I am wondering what is a better approach to my current leakage prone approach.

**Header file:**

```
// this is the header file of stack data structure.

#ifndef MY_STACK_H
#define MY_STACK_H

class Node 
{
private:
    int number;
    Node * next;

public:
    Node(){number = 0; next = NULL;}

    Node(int initialNumber, Node * initialNext = NULL)
    {
        number = initialNumber;
        next = initialNext;
    }

    // copy constructor
    Node(Node & copyFromNode) 
    {
        this->number    =   copyFromNode.getNumber();
        this->next      =   copyFromNode.getNext();
    }


    // setters & getters
    int getNumber() {return number;}
    Node * getNext()    {return next;}
    void setNumber(int newNumber)   {number = newNumber;}
    void setNext(Node * newNext)    {next = newNext;}
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node * head;

public:
    LinkedList(){head = NULL;}

    // very similar to Stack::push()
    void addFirst(Node *newNode)
    {
        newNode->setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
    }

    // somehow similar to Stack::pop()
    void deleteFirst()
    {
        if (head == NULL)
            return;
        else
        {
            Node * temp = head;
            head = head->getNext();
            delete temp;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty()      {return (head == NULL);}
    Node * getHead()    {return head;}

    // there is no setter to head 
    // since head should be maintained by addFirst() & deleteFirst() only.
};

class Stack 
{
private:
    Node * top;
    LinkedList ll;
public:
    Stack(){top = NULL; }

    // push new node to the stack
    // new node will become the new top of stack
    void push(Node * newNode);

    // it checks if the stack is empty or not. 
    bool isEmpty();

    // it copies the top node on stack,
    // without deleting it. 
    Node * peek();

    // it copies the top node on stack, 
    // and deletes the node from stack. 
    Node * pop();
};

#endif
```

**.cpp file:**

```
// implementation for the stack


#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

void Stack::push(Node * newNode)
{
    ll.addFirst(newNode);
    top = ll.getHead();
}

bool Stack::isEmpty()
{
    if(top == NULL)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

Node * Stack::peek()
{
    // make a copy, erase next link and return 
    // copy is made by calling copy construtor
    Node * copy = new Node(*top);   // ?? asks for reference but pointer is given

    return copy;
}

Node * Stack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        Node * copy = new Node(*top);
        ll.deleteFirst();
        top = ll.getHead();
        return copy;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack stack;

    Node * nd1 = new Node(100);
    Node * nd2 = new Node(200);

    // test push()
    stack.push(nd1);
    stack.push(nd2);

    // test isEmpty()
    cout<<"Test: isEmpty(): "<< stack.isEmpty()<<endl;


    // test peek()
    cout<<"Test: peek(): "<<stack.peek()->getNumber()<<endl;


    // test pop()
    cout<<"Test: pop()"<<stack.pop()->getNumber()<<endl;
    cout<<"Test: pop()"<<stack.pop()->getNumber()<<endl;

    cout<<"Test: isEmpty(): "<<stack.isEmpty()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't allocate nodes until you *really* need to.

`LinkedList` should not expose that it has nodes. `addFirst` should take an int to be stored in the node and `getHead` should return the value in the head node.

```
    void addFirst(int number )
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->setNumber(number);
        newNode->setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
    }
    int getHead()    {return head->number;}
```

Same in stack don't expose that it deals in nodes and don't let calling code access them. That way you have more control over the lifetimes.

Comment: This is also what the C++ `<stack>`implementation does. You could return a reference from `getHead`/`peek` though. For complex types, copies should be avoided – which is also why `<stack>` doesn't return anything from `pop`, because it can't return a reference there. A copy constructor could throw and then the popped element would get lost.

Comment: @FelixDombek I'd been wondering why so many STL data structures are set up that way. Makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't use `NULL` unless you have to**

Some IDEs will refuse to compile your code unless you include `<cstdlib>` so that `NULL` is available. If you compile using a C++ compiler using latest standards, you could use `nullptr` instead, since it is a language construct in those versions and does not require including anything.

**Minor improvements**

```
//bool Stack::isEmpty()
//{
//    if(top == NULL)
//        return true;
//    else
//        return false;
//}

bool Stack::isEmpty()
{
    return top == nullptr;
}
```

and

```
//Node * Stack::pop()
//{
//
//    if (isEmpty())
//        return NULL;
//    else
//    {
//        Node * copy = new Node(*top);
//        ll.deleteFirst();
//        top = ll.getHead();
//        return copy;
//    }
//}

Node * Stack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node * copy = new Node(*top);
    ll.deleteFirst();
    top = ll.getHead();
    return copy;
}
```

**Alternative implementation**

It's not difficult to devise a generic stack:

**my_stack.h**

```
#ifndef MY_STACK_H
#define MY_STACK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyStack {

    std::vector<T> storage;
    void check_not_empty()
    {
        if (storage.empty())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{"Peeking from an empty stack."};
        }
    }

public:
    void push(const T& element)
    {
        storage.push_back(element);
    }

    void pop()
    {
        check_not_empty();
        storage.pop_back();
    }

    const T& peek() const
    {
        check_not_empty();
        return storage[storage.size() - 1];
    }

    size_t size()
    {
        return storage.size();
    }

    bool is_empty()
    {
        return storage.empty();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyStack<T>& stack)
    {
        os << "[";
        std::string separator = "";

        for (size_t i = 0; i != stack.storage.size(); ++i)
        {
            os << separator << stack.storage[i];
            separator = ", ";
        }

        return os << "]";
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "my_stack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyStack<int> stack;

    cout << stack << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        stack.push(i);
        cout << stack << endl;
    }

    while (!stack.is_empty())
    {
        stack.pop();
        cout << stack << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `nullptr` is a C++11 language construct. If you are going to assume that the OP has access to C++11 then you should _definitely_ point out smart pointers.

Comment: @GillBates Point. I made more explicit notice on modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers bring up good points, but, architecturally, the problem is that your linked list acquires control of `Node`s and offers no way to relinquish it.  Think about it: in `deleteFirst`, you delete your old list head , but how do you know that head was heapalloc'd in the first place?

Consider the following:

```
void example(void)
{
    LinkedList ll;
    Node n(5, nullptr);
    ll.addFirst(&n);
    ll.deleteFirst();
 }
```

Now you're going to`delete` a portion of the stack.

Instead, `deleteFirst` should remove *and return* the head, instead of deleting it.  Then the consumer can delete it as necessary (or not).  Then a regular user can write something like

```
void example(void)
{
    LinkedList ll;
    ll.addFirst(new Node(5, nullptr));
    delete ll.deleteFirst();
 }
```

and my example above compiles.  So how do we implement this?

```
Node *deleteFirst(void)
{
    Node *const temp(head);
    if(head)
    {
        head = head->getNext();
    }
    return temp;
 }
```

At this point, you may want to rename `deleteFirst`; for the sake of fidelity to the problem, I shan't.   Now you can write your stack as

```
Node &Stack::peek(void)
{
    return *top;
}
Node *Stack::pop(void)
{
    return isEmpty() ? nullptr : ll.deleteFirst();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your problem is that you fear that the user may not delete the node once popped. There are many levels at which you may do something.

**Get your resource management straight**

Have a look at `unique_ptr`. A `unique_ptr` represents a unique owner of a resource, responsible for freeing the resource. It may not be copied, only moved. In your case, when popping, you want to give the ownership back to the user, have `pop`return a `unique_ptr<Node>` by value. Reserve plain pointers as non-owners (a.k.a. observers) of the resource.

All your memory management problems will disappear unless the user explicitly does something dangerous. The dangerous will be made verbose.

If you want a quick look at resource management in C++11 and later, you may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826952/2071258 (this is an answer of mine)

**Fix your interface. Do not expose the nodes**

The fact that there are `Node`s is purely an implementation detail, worse, it fails to hide the fact that your `Stack` is implemented over a `LinkedList` (since `Node` belongs to `LinkedList`). Instead of returning a pointer to a node when popping, return a value. By value, since the node, containing the value, disappears.